# How to concatenate period in eval ASP.net

Tags: html, asp.net, eval

I have a ASP.net Label whose Text is defined as follows

```
Text='<%# Eval("Price", "{0:&pound;0.00 ex. VAT}") %>'
```

This displays the label as follows ignoring the 'period' between ex and VAT. How do i handle this?

£99.99 ex VAT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below instead:

```
Text='<%# Eval("Price", "{0:&pound;0.00}") + " ex. VAT" %>'
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
Text='<%# Eval("Price", @"{0:#;0.00 ex. VAT}") %>'
```

Should do the trick.